# elasticsearch completion field not deleting

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I have a simple user info document which includes a completion field.

Mapping:

```
      "properties" : {
        "fname" : { "type" : "string" },
        "lname" : { "type" : "string" },
        "dob" : { "type" : "string" },
        "sex" : { "type" : "string" },
        "autocomplete" : {
          "type" :     "completion"
         }
      }
```

This is an example of my document.

```
"person" : {
            "sex"       : "Male",
            "dob"      : "11/11/2014",         
            "fname"      : "Julie",
            "lname"      : "Thomas",
            "autocomplete"      : "Julie Thomas"
  }
```

The complete suggestion query works perfectly fine. But when I delete this document, the complete suggestion still exist for "Julie Thomas" when I expect this to be deleted as well.

Any suggestion on what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am having this problem too.  According to the ElasticSearch documentation, completion suggestions need to be expunged from the index using the [Optimize command](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-optimize.html).  This is what they say at the bottom of [the Completion Suggester Docs](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#indexing).

> The suggest data structure might not reflect deletes on documents
>   immediately. You may need to do an Optimize for that. You can call
>   optimize with the only_expunge_deletes=true to only cater for deletes
>   or alternatively call a Merge operation.

... that said.  I did this:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://server:9200/attribute/_optimize?pretty' -d '{
    "only_expunge_deletes": true
}'
```

and the deleted doc still shows up in the completion suggester, even though it does not show up in queries or filters.

... Sorry.  Not much of an answer...  It's supposed to be the answer, but it might not work for you, just as it's not working for me.

Comment: yes, I tried optimize with only_expunge_deletes. Does not work. I even waited for 30 sec, 1 min and 5 mins... just so if there was refresh waiting to happen. No change. Stuck as you are!

Comment: So...  maybe the only way to solve this is to not use ElasticSearch. ;)  ... or perhaps to use index-time search, instead of the very feature they supposedly put in for this purpose?

Comment: Did they ever expunge at all?

Answer (score 1):

We might have to move to [Index-Time Search](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html), which uses a 1-character ngram and do a normal _search query.

Comment: The problem with this is ngram increases the index size terribly. At least in my use-case. Not that I set the max gram to 20 or 50 but the size of my data and use case, we just could not move forward with ngram. Hope you are able to. I am opening a issue with es github on the suggester.

Comment: There is already an issue and some jerk closed it calling it a feature.   it will be ready in ES 2.0  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/117

Comment: this link is better, and StackOverflow won't let me edit that comment. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7761

Answer (score 0):

Adding an id field to the data, and then refrencing that id field for delete and update, works for us

```
"index":{"_index":"esIndex","_type":"document","_id":"23d68f060118fbeee699d14eff044a1f"}}
 {"text":"vision zero","id":"23d68f060118fbeee699d14eff044a1f","suggest":{"input":"vision zero","payload":{"entity_id":"23d68f060118fbeee699d14eff044a1f"}},"type":"Content"}
```

Something like the above bulk query data, notice the **id** field in the data. If we don't put it, we face same issue that after deleting document, it still show up in suggestions.